# Как проверить что содержимое файла в формате XML? Java

Tags: java, xml, io, xmlparser

Нужно проверить именно содержимое, а не расширение. Достаточно ли проверить первую строку `FileReader'ом` на наличие `<?xml` или есть более правильный вариант?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете написать sax-парсер и при попытке прочитать файл, если он не является xml - бросит ошибку, вы ее перехватите и выведете сообщение (или что там надо). Наверное и с другими парсерами также - jaxb, dom